# losing precision in google maps GeoPoint class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, precision

I'm trying to put some geolocation data from Google Maps into a database. But passing around a GeoPoint object, I seem to be loosing a ton of precision.

I get an Intent as a result of an onActivityResult response, in the Intent is extra data for a geopoint:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG,String.format("doMark returns with %d", resultCode));


    int lat = data.getIntExtra("MARK_LAT", 0);
    int lng = data.getIntExtra("MARK_LNG", 0);

    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Orig lat/lng %d:%d", lat, lng));

    OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(lat,lng), "ID", "");

    Log.d(TAG, String.format("GeoPoint lat/lng %d:%d", 
            oi.getPoint().getLatitudeE6(),
            oi.getPoint().getLongitudeE6()));

    m_data.addMarker(m_gp, data.getIntExtra("MARK_ID", R.drawable.tile5));

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In the logcat I get:

03-08 10:28:16.164: D/TREASUREACTIVITY(1653): Orig lat/lng 42234412:-70999749
03-08 10:28:16.164: D/TREASUREACTIVITY(1653): GeoPoint lat/lng 42234412:-70999749

That looks good! The GeoPoint lat/lng are the same as the input values.

The m_data.addMarker() function is thus:

```
public void addMarker(GeoPoint p, int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("TIME", System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put("LAT", p.getLatitudeE6());
    values.put("LNG", p.getLongitudeE6());
    values.put("MARK_ID", id);
    db.insert("MARKER", null, values);
    Log.d(TAG,String.format("INSERT MARKER %d %d",p.getLatitudeE6(),
            p.getLongitudeE6()));
    db.close();
}
```

The logcat from addMarker() is:

03-08 10:28:16.194: D/DDATA(1653): INSERT MARKER 42234000 -71000000

I'm presuming there's some kind of conversion/promotion going on behind the scenes... but the code is pretty straight forward.

Any guess as to where the precision went?

Comment: what is m_gp and where is it created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addMarker` call is using `m_gp`, not `oi.getPoint()` - so it's not using the same value at all.

Maybe that's not the real problem, but you may just need:

```
m_data.addMarker(oi.getPoint(), data.getIntExtra("MARK_ID", R.drawable.tile5));
```

Comment: ug... big fingers, little buttons. Tks!